# Pattern identification in real (conically deformed) images

Tags: computer-science, projective-geometry, image-processing, pattern-recognition, pattern-matching

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

I'm in an analysis process of some photographs (as taken by a camera, thus they are conically deformed).
I'm already able to automatically identify some elements and its type in them. I know those elements are organized in a grid pattern, which is also known. I give an example in the following image:

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/186nW.png)

In the example, I have Stage 3 (without the lines, just the elements) and I know those elements originally followed the Stage 1 pattern. Please, note that there are some lines of the original grid from where I can't identify any elements.

The question is: Is it possible to match elements from Stage 3 to the corresponding ones in Stage 1? The desired result would be the ids of the next image:

[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seaUj.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dear José VZS. It is clear that there is some geometry involved in this problem and it might be interesting for people here. But it is not quite clear what you expect in your question. It seems as if you are looking for an algorithm that does this automatically given the images as input. If so, this question does not belong on this forum. If that is not the case and you are looking for some mathematical insights, please specify exactly the input and desired output of your problem.

Comment: For example: "Given are coordinates of each shape along with its type for the deformed image and the original. Can we assign each shape of the deformed image to one in the original?".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.